# Angular : Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-services

I was trying to integrate google cloud firestore in my angular app and it lead to that error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>   [image: full error log]

when I initiate my service into the constructor

this the service I am using :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection,
        AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Idata } from '../model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  // collections initialisation
  datas: Observable<Idata[]>;
  dataCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Idata>;
  dataDocumment: AngularFirestoreDocument<Idata>;
  data: Observable<Idata>;
  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
   }

   // get all documents for caucus
   getDataCaucus() {
    this.dataCollection = this.afs.collection('eluCC');
    this.datas = this.afs.collection('eluCC').snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Idata;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
     return this.datas;
   }
}
```

and this is how I initiate it into my component

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';

import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

declare interface DataTable {
    headerRow: string[];
    footerRow: string[];
    dataRows: string[][];
  }
declare var $:any;


@Component({
    selector: 'app-grid-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'grid.component.html'
})

export class GridSystemComponent {
    temp = [];
    rows = [];

    public dataTable: DataTable;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,private dataService: DataService) { 
         this.dataService.getDataCaucus().subscribe((datas) => {
           this.temp = [...datas];
           this.rows = datas;
           console.log(datas);
         });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataTable = {
            headerRow: [ 'Name', 'Position', 'Office', 'Age', 'Date', 'Actions' ],
            footerRow: [ 'Name', 'Position', 'Office', 'Age', 'Start Date', 'Actions' ],

            dataRows: [
                ['Airi Satou', 'Andrew Mike', 'Develop', '2013', '99,225', ''],
                ['Angelica Ramos', 'John Doe', 'Design', '2012', '89,241', 'btn-round'],
                ['Ashton Cox', 'Alex Mike', 'Design', '2010', '92,144', 'btn-simple'],
                ['Bradley Greer', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Brenden Wagner', 'Paul Dickens', 'Communication', '2015', '69,201', ''],
                ['Brielle Williamson', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Caesar Vance', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Cedric Kelly', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Charde Marshall', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Colleen Hurst', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Dai Rios', 'Andrew Mike', 'Develop', '2013', '99,225', ''],
                ['Doris Wilder', 'John Doe', 'Design', '2012', '89,241', 'btn-round'],
                ['Fiona Green', 'Alex Mike', 'Design', '2010', '92,144', 'btn-simple'],
                ['Garrett Winters', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Gavin Cortez', 'Paul Dickens', 'Communication', '2015', '69,201', ''],
                ['Gavin Joyce', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Gloria Little', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Haley Kennedy', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Herrod Chandler', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Hope Fuentes', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Howard Hatfield', 'Andrew Mike', 'Develop', '2013', '99,225', ''],
                ['Jena Gaines', 'John Doe', 'Design', '2012', '89,241', 'btn-round'],
                ['Jenette Caldwell', 'Alex Mike', 'Design', '2010', '92,144', 'btn-simple'],
                ['Jennifer Chang', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Martena Mccray', 'Paul Dickens', 'Communication', '2015', '69,201', ''],
                ['Michael Silva', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Michelle House', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round'],
                ['Paul Byrd', 'Mike Monday', 'Marketing', '2013', '49,990', 'btn-round']
            ]
         };

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('#datatables').DataTable({
            'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
            'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']],
            responsive: true,
            language: {
            search: '_INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search records',
            }

        });

        const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

        // Edit record
        table.on( 'click', '.edit', function () {
            const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            const data = table.row($tr).data();
            alert( 'You press on Row: ' + data[0] + ' ' + data[1] + ' ' + data[2] + '\'s row.' );
        } );

        // Delete a record
        table.on( 'click', '.remove', function (e: any) {
            const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            table.row($tr).remove().draw();
            e.preventDefault();
        } );

        // Like record
        table.on( 'click', '.like', function () {
            alert('You clicked on Like button');
        });
    }
}
```

I have to mention that my app have several module and I have set the provider for the same service in each of them and all the component return the same mistake.

Any idea of what might cause this?

Comment: Could you add more details? Which line is throwing this error? Don't you need to wait for some Google services to be loaded before executing your app?

Comment: That the problem it is not throwing error from any line, I will update teh question with the full error message. and no I don't need to wait for any google services

Comment: did you properly install the firestore plugin as per the instructions?  https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

Comment: yes I did and i double-checked it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're using Rxjs 5.x.

You have to upgrade Rxjs to 6.0+. [Follow the docs.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) (It is pretty easy)

In rxjs 6.0 the import statement has been changed & `.map` is also changed in term of structure.

From rxjs 6.0 they introduced a new operator called `.pipe` where you can perform multiple operation one by one.

Example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.datas = this.afs.collection('eluCC').snapshotChanges()
   .pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Idata;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        })
      })
   );
```

---

*In case you don't want to upgrade Rxj`(I don't why - it is pretty easy really), downgrade to angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.6 version **(not recommended)**.` 
npm i -s angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6`*

Comment: Which version you're using for `angularfire2`, `angular` & `rxjs`? @Geeksan

Comment: I am using angular 5.2.0, "rxjs": "5.5.6" and    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",

Comment: I just tried your edit  snipset and it is still showing the same error

Comment: Ops! I just found, you've to use `rxjs 6.0`. Upgrade rxjs to 6.0. Here is the doc https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md

Comment: In case you don't want to upgrade Rxjs (I don't why - it is pretty easy), back to `angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.6` version (not recommended). `npm i -s angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6`

Comment: this works sir, I updated the rxjs and everything is working just fine now. Thank you. I recommend you to edit your answer so i could mark it as answered

Answer (score 10):

You need to upgrade your rxjs to version 6.0+. If you are on Angular 6 you will alos need to install rxjs-compat. Just run the commnd below to solve both problems

npm install rxjs@6.0 rxjs-compat --save